# Is there a way to move questions from stackoverflow to this site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get a "Belongs on StackOverflow" as a closing reason?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-we-get-a-belongs-on-stackoverflow-as-a-closing-reason)

It would be nice if some questions such as the famous quote and cartoon questions from StackOverflow could be copied or moved to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. I'm not sure what the criteria for getting this feature is, but it has been discussed on Stack Overflow Meta (don't have any links at this time, but I can dig them up). I would suspect it wouldn't happen until we are out of beta, though.

Comment: Migration paths will be set up once the site goes fully live with its proper domain name.